# Change template dynamically

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, redirect, page-template, template-redirect

Is it possible to change the template loaded for a page, as it loads, without having to change the record in the database?

I suspect it can be done with the `template_redirect` action, and the will probably have something to do with the template-loader.php file in the WP core, but I can't figure it out.

Any pointers would be grand!!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone comes here to copy pasta without looking at the codex.

**THE APPROPRIATE FILTER IS »`template_include`«**

See: [Codex - Filter Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/)

As Radek pointed out that method can destroy your theme.

*Additional information*: The article »[Don’t use template_redirect to load an alternative template file](https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/)« by Mark Jaquith, where he says, in a nutshell, `template_redirect` is for *redirects*, `template_include` is for *includes*.

Comment: This is best answer, since template_redirect is used for what it says - page redirection.